# how to get the context menu after perform AXShowMenu in AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript

my code like this

```
tell button 1 of window 1
    perform action "AXShowMenu"
    delay 0.2
end tell
```

after the menu is shown, how to get the menu? many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's the items of `menu 1` of the drop down button:

```
tell button 1 of window 1
    click
    delay 0.2
    get every menu item of menu 1
    --click menu item "name" of menu 1
end tell
```

Comment: i use Accessibility Inspector find the context menu's parent is button 1, but, when i use get every ui element of button 1, always gets empty list

Comment: Are you sure it's button 1? Button 1-3 are actualy the red, yellow and green on the upper left corner of the window.

Comment: the code is simple test, i mean how to get the context menu, i tried lots of methods do it, but all failed, hope some one can help me, my email is neocanable at gmail dot com, email me ,i can give u all of my code